# Angular + Material - How to handle multiple checkboxes with formgroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of interests i am getting from the backend. I want a user to be able to select the interests they want. I will store only the interests they checked in the DB and pre-populate when they load the page. But first i need to get these interests the user has selected.

interest.component.ts

```
export class InterestsComponent implements OnInit {

  interestFormGroup : FormGroup
  interests:any;
  selected: any;


  constructor(public interestService: InterestService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.interestFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      interests: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });


    this.interestService.all().subscribe((res) => {

      this.interests = res;

    });

  }

  change() {
    console.log(this.interestFormGroup.value);
  }

}
```

interest.component.html

```
<div id="interest">

    <div class="interest-list">

        <form [formGroup]="interestFormGroup">
            <div *ngFor="let interest of interests" >
                <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formNameArray="interests" (change)="change()">{{interest}}</mat-checkbox>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

In my console.log on the change event it shows there is no values being added to the interests array within the interestFormGroup. Even tho the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should add controls to `FormArray` manually like:

```typescript
this.interests = res;
const formArray = this.interestFormGroup.get('interests') as FormArray;
this.interests.forEach(x => formArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
```

then change template as follows:

```html
<form [formGroup]="interestFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
   <ng-container formArrayName="interests">
      <div *ngFor="let interest of interests; let i = index" >
         <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [formControlName]="i">
           {{interest}}
         </mat-checkbox>
      </div>
   </ng-container>
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And when you will submit form you need to transform `FormArray` values to your desired result:

```typescript
submit() {
  const result = Object.assign({}, 
    this.interestFormGroup.value, { 
      interests: this.interests
        .filter((x, i) => !!this.interestFormGroup.value.interests[i])});

  console.log(result);
}
```

Alternative solution is listen `change` event and manually add and remove value to `FormArray`:

```typescript
<div *ngFor="let interest of interests; let i = index" >
   <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" 
                (change)="onChange($event)" [value]="interest">{{interest}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>

onChange(event) {
  const interests = <FormArray>this.interestFormGroup.get('interests') as FormArray;

  if(event.checked) {
    interests.push(new FormControl(event.source.value))
  } else {
    const i = interests.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === event.source.value);
    interests.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyfg2z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: From the stackblitz thats not what i want, it returns an array of true and false values, when i actually want the value of the interest. As true and false values don't actually tell me what interest was selected as the key is the index. I don't even know why the index is added here? Seems like an over complicated solution to something thats meant to be simple.

Comment: So in that stackbltiz example it should return an array of interests with values interest1,interest2,interest3 not 0:true 1:true 2:true

Comment: Did you try to submit form? Look at the console

Comment: @KHAN I added alternative solution. See if it helped

Comment: this does not seem to work properly. if you add interest3 and try to remove it does not work

Comment: @KHAN Updated example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyfg2z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you that seems to work, but finally how would you pre-populate the checkboxes as checked when i retrieve the values from the DB?

Comment: Simply pushing the values into the formarray is not enough as they checkboxes will not be checked. There is no binding here, i wonder if there is an easier way with ngmodel.

Comment: I was banging my head for hours with this. Thanks, my friend. Will pay beer.

Comment: @yurzui how to make select all checkbox in that example? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @yurzui does it support two way binding? for ex. if i want to set `interent1` as checked . ` this.interestFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      interests: this.formBuilder.array(["interest1"])
    });`